# Greenplum: Purging database Logs

Tags: database, postgresql, data-warehouse, greenplum

is there any direct utility available to purge older logs from GP database, If i do it manually it is taking lot of time as there are 100+ segments, i have to go to each server and delete the logs files manually.

Other details: GP version - 4.3.X.X(Software Only Solution)

Cluster Config- 2+10

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a cron job and use gpssh to do this.  For example:

```
gpssh -f ~/host_list -e 'for i in $(find /data/primary/gpseg*/pg_log/ -name "*.csv" -ctime +60); do rm $i; done'
```

This will remove files in pg_log on all segments that are over 2 months old.  Of course, you should test this and make sure the path to pg_log is correct.

Comment: Thanks Jon, It is really helpful, I also want to take count and size of all log files that are 2 month old before deleting. Also i have two diff data directories /data1, /data2 on segments and /data on master.

Comment: count: gpssh -f ~/host_list -e 'find /data*/primary/gpseg*/pg_log/ -name "*.csv" -ctime +60 | wc -l'

Comment: file sizes: gpssh -f ~/host_list -e 'find /data*/primary/gpseg*/pg_log/ -name "*.csv" -ctime +60 -exec ls -l {} \;'

Comment: Thanks Jon, i will try it out